# Barcode Reader using zbar sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, zbar-sdk

I am working in barcode reader. I am using Zbar Sdk for read a barcode.My problem is that, very small barcode are not read. I am confusing about : Is this a camera problem (iPad 2) or sdk problem plz suggest me.

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The iPad 2 camera does not have auto-focus. Zbar doesn't play well with fixed focus cameras:

> If your camera is fixed focus, you can try trading off between resolution and focus by playing with the distance of the symbol from the lens. ymmv, but usually your only recourse in this case is to use a better capture device!

Comment: same problem occurs in iPhone 4s.plz ,Give me any idea for this.